# constructing bases in $\mathbb R^2$ to find diagonalization of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let A = $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1   \\
    1 & 1   \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Construct bases $\beta,\gamma $ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $[A]_{\beta}^{\gamma}$   is a diagonal matrix

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGcyc.png)

Answer (score 1):

The bases $\{\beta,\gamma\}$ will be two eigen vectors corresponding to the two eigen values 0 and 2 of $A$, which are respectively $\beta=(1,-1)^t$ and $\gamma=(1,1)^t$. Note that $A\beta=0$ and $A\gamma=2\gamma$.

Hence, with respect to $\{\beta,\gamma\}$,$$A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0   \\
    0 & 2   \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you @ Tomath

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^2-1=0\implies x=0,2$ are the e-values.

We need a basis of eigenvectors.
$Ax=0\implies x=s\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$. And, $Ax=2x\implies x=t\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

$\therefore \gamma =\beta=\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$  will do.

In fact, 
 $[A]_{\beta}^{\gamma}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}A \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you @Chris Custer, I was struggling to find  (0 0, 0 2) until I realized from your work where it is defined in the book I am using